# What `be` can add to following statement?

Tags: grammar

Context: I asked a reason for a statement in Question and answer forum. I got two possibilities in this scenario.

```
1. How can it be possible?

            OR 
2. How can it possible?
```

My question is how `be` changed context and meaning of my scenario?

PS: Any source of reading required please comment.

Comment: 'be' is what makes it grammatical.

Comment: Without *be*, the sentence has no meaning. (Of course, other words could be used. For instance, *How can it appear possible?* Although a bit strange, it's still grammatical and has meaning in the right context. But you need to having something between *it* and *possible*.)

Comment: The verb *be* is often called a "linking verb". In this instance, it's quite apt: you have nothing linking together *it* and *possible*. I think people in our sister site may be best able to explain and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *How can it possible

is not grammatical.

Modals like "can" must be followed by a verb (except in elliptical answers like "Can you do it? Yes, I can", where the verb is understood).